# On one page click link to another page show div and expand div

Tags: jquery, html, css

On one page I have this:
(1) mini navigation
(2) each link in mini nav (1) shows or hides a div (think tabs) below it
(3) within each hidden div (2) is another show/hide div effect (think accordion)

On another page I want this:
* link that when clicked, goes to the page above, navigates to the correct hidden "tab" (2), and then expands (shows) a div in the accordion (3).

PROBLEM
Everything works, but now I want to implement a link on another page to show the second hidden div and one of the accordions. I do not know how to accomplish this. Ideas? Thoughts?

FIDDLE
http://jsfiddle.net/zuhloobie/2jtqroLL/1/

Here is a graphic of what I want to accomplish: [image: external-link-show]

HTML TRIGGER FOR ONE OF THE MINI NAV LINKS TO SHOW ITS HIDDEN DIV

```
<a href="#subDivTab1" class="subDivSwitchLink">overview</a>
```

JQUERY DIV SWITCH FOR THE MINI NAV

```
$(function(){
$('a.subDivSwitchLink').click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this),
    containerSelector = $this.attr('href'),
    $links = $('a.subDivSwitchLink');
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div.subDivSwitch').not(containerSelector).hide();
    $(containerSelector).show();
    $links.not($this).toggleClass('subTitleActive', false);
    $this.toggleClass('subTitleActive', true);
});
var target = '#'+'subDivTab1';
$('a[href="'+target+'"].subDivSwitchLink').click();
});
```

JQUERY FOR THE HIDDEN ACCORDION

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#drawer > ul > li:has(ul)').addClass("has-sub");
        $('#drawer > ul > li > a').click(function() {
            var checkElement = $(this).next();
            $('#drawer li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');   
            if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
                checkElement.slideUp('normal');
            }
            if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $('#drawer ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                checkElement.slideDown('normal');
            }
            if (checkElement.is('ul')) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;    
            }       
        });
    });
```

HTML FOR ONE OF HIDDEN DIV WITH ACCORDION

```
<div id="subDivTab2" class="subDivSwitch">
<div class="subRightSectionTitle soft">hidden div title2
</div>
<div class="subRightSectionText ulineGray"><span class="subRightSectionTextHeader">hidden div text2</span>
</div>
<div id="drawer" class="softDrawer">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;">hidden accordion title1</a>
            <ul>
                <li>hidden accordion text1</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;">hidden accordion title2</a>
            <ul>
                <li>hidden accordion text1</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: cool story bro. whats your question?

Comment: Bro, ah yes - forgot that part. I do not know how to go about this, does anyone have any ideas? [forgive my assumption of intuitively obvious question asking ;)]

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for that?

Comment: I will try...please hold :) a lot of code to simplify...

Comment: FIDDLE --> http://jsfiddle.net/zuhloobie/2jtqroLL/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just do query string when user clicks on the link add a query string to a link on page 1

```
<a href="page2.html?showdiv=true">page2</a>
```

on page one read the query string

```
<script>
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
   if(getParameterByName('showdiv')=="true")
   {
         //show div and link.
   }
});
</script>
```

Comment: My problem is that I don't understand how I would link to a specific hidden section (in my case "sublink 2", as well as opening a specific accordion (in my case "accordion2 title")...and how jquery  code would be incorporated to accomplish those parameters. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zuhloobie/2jtqroLL/1/

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to pass the desired parameters via link.  You can use cookies, or one method I've used, which is to append to the link url as query parameters. Create your link and add ?tab=3 for example. The target page needs a query string parser script to grab those for your use, like your requirement: 'navigates to the correct hidden "tab" and then expands (shows) a div in the accordion'.

```js
// plain vanilla javascript - to test, try pasting in Chrome console, append some parameters to your URL, for example: mypage.html?nav=4&accordian=7 

    function getURLparams(paramName) {
      var sURL = window.document.URL.toString();
      if (sURL.indexOf("?") > 0) {
        var arrParams = sURL.split("?");
        var arrURLParams = arrParams[1].split("&");
        var arrParamNames = new Array(arrURLParams.length);
        var arrParamValues = new Array(arrURLParams.length);
        var i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < arrURLParams.length; i++) {
          var sParam =  arrURLParams[i].split("=");
          arrParamNames[i] = sParam[0];
          if (sParam[1] != "") {
            arrParamValues[i] = unescape(sParam[1]);
          } else {
            arrParamValues[i] = "no values";
          }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < arrURLParams.length; i++) {
          if(arrParamNames[i] == paramName){
            return arrParamValues[i];
          }
        }
        return "no parameters";
      }
    }
   
   var navTarget = getURLparams('nav')
   var accTarget = getURLparams('accordian')
   
   // Now you can change nav 2 style and open accordian 3:
   //  var sLink = '#subLink' + navTarget;
   //  var sDivTab = '#subDivTab' + accTarget;
   //  sLink.css('font-size','24px');
   //  sDivTab.show();
```

```html
<!-- URL with parameter queries -->
<a href="http://www.example.com/targetPage.html?nav=2&accordian=3">Link to nav 2 and accordian 3</a>
```

Comment: I think I follow - dangerously close to exceeding my knowledge here. I do really like the idea of query parameters which you showed. I understand your link that goes to nav2 and accordion 3 - but how do I assign those two parameters on the target page so the link knows where to go?

Comment: Not sure if you saw the fiddle i recently added: http://jsfiddle.net/zuhloobie/2jtqroLL/1/

Comment: @chris - take a look at the commented out jquery code in the example and those 2 vars just before. eg. If the navTarget returns '3' because the URL included ?nav=3 then you can use that to append to your jquery element and target it.  So var sLink = '#subLink' + navTarget;  if (sLink == #subLink3) then change the css:
 sLink.css('font-size','24px');

Comment: I'm sorry - no offense to you, but I'm just not getting it. I understand the logic behind the link parameters. I understand what we are trying to do. I understand that ?nav will take you to the right tab and ?accordion will take you to the right accordion. I just don't understand how to connect the dots in my particular code. As you can see, I'm not the most advanced jquery/js coder & I don't have formal training. But I'm learning. It's like Spanish. I can understand a lot of it & speak a little, but if I'm thrown into Mexico then I just stare into space with confusion. This feels like Mexico.

Comment: Is there a similar example somewhere that shows this in action? I know you all don't like the "do it for me now" thing and that isn't my intention. I'm visual so maybe that would help me understand.